# New react native element is not accessible

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, accessibility

I'm working on react-native project (main target is iPhone 6) and got some problems with including new elements in accessibility chain. For some reasons Voice Over does not update when new element appears after re-rendering. Hidden button does not appear in accessibility chain after running showButton() method. It becomes visible, but iOS Voice Over does not see it. The problem occurs only when app does something asynchronously. Here is my code:

```js
export default class SmartView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showButton: false,
    }
  }

  showButton = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ showButton: true })
    }, 500)
  }

  render() {
    const { showButton } = this.state
    return (
      <View style={style.root}>
        <Button
          onPress={this.showButton}
          accessibilityRole="button"
          accessibilityTraits="button"
          accessibilityLabel="appeared"
          accessible
          simple
        >
          <Text>Appeared</Text>
        </Button>
        {showButton && (
          <Button
            accessibilityRole="button"
            accessibilityTraits="button"
            accessibilityLabel="appeared"
            accessible
            simple
          >
            <Text>Hidden</Text>
          </Button>
        )}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

So, if I remove `setTimeout` and do state updating in current js stream, everything work fine. Is there any possibility to make something like `VoiceOverReload()`?

I use: react-native v0.59.9 and iPhone 6, software version 12.4

Thanks.

Comment: What is `Voice Over` and `VoiceOverReload()`?  You say these are the problem areas, I do not see them in the code at all?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I mean hidden button does not appear in accessibility chain after running `showButton()` method. It becomes visible, but iOS Voice Over does not see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below demo works fine, probably your custom `Button` component has issues

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

export default function Screen () {
  const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false)
  function handleShow () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowButton(true)
    }, 1000)
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 40 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={handleShow}
        accessibilityRole='button'
        accessibilityTraits='button'
        accessibilityLabel='This button label is long for demo'
        accessible
        >
        <Text>Appeared</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {showButton && (
        <TouchableOpacity
          accessibilityRole='button'
          accessibilityTraits='button'
          accessibilityLabel='hidden'
          accessible
        >
          <Text>Hidden</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view is going to update and you need voice over to detect the change faster, the  you can add the following trait to the parent view: `frequentUpdates`. This will be the equivalent of setting "Updates Frequently" on the accessibility properties in XCode, as explained in the following answer: [Making dynamically updating content in a UITableView accessible for VoiceOver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583040/making-dynamically-updating-content-in-a-uitableview-accessible-for-voiceover)

This works for ReactNative 0.59, though its deprecated and I don't know how to do it in newer versions of RN.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Unfortunately it does not help, I added `accessibilityTraits="frequentUpdates"` to parent `View` element located in `render()` method (code above) but everything remains the same.